# VBA userforms and OneDrive Sync - Simultaneouly Submiting Data

Tags: excel, vba, userform, onedrive

I have a userform in excel VBA that about 40 people use. When submitting data through the userform to write on the sheet it works perfectly. However, I tested with 5 users simultaneously using this same form and it seems like OneDrive syncing starts to mess up with the submitions (lines are being overwritten).

Is there a work around so that this overwritting does not happen when users are submiting data simultaneously?

Comment: It very much sounds like you're (ab)using Excel as a database.

Comment: Hello BigBen, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I do completly agree with your comment, I am indeed abusing Excel as a database. But how would I be able to actually have a file available to 50+ people, not having issues of syncing, no access to company servers and only with MS Office? I mean... is it even possible or would I have to actually limit to 1 user editing at a time.

Comment: I'd use an actual database for this, to be honest. Excel really isn't designed for this sort of setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much information about how you've set this up or how it's used but, as I'm picturing the shared workbook, you could determine and "reserve" the destination location upon opening of the userform, instead of upon completion.

There are a number of issues you'd have to work through, as [co-authoring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104) in this way can be tricky, and this is not ideal. Ideally you'd be transitioning to MS Access or another relational database.  (If you already know some basic VBA, the learning curve isn't as steep as it might seem.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply ashleedawg.

Wouldn't reserving a destination location upon opening present the same sync issue as on completion?

I actually never worked with MS Access (other than for a brief time in College). Would it work as a database receiving data from somewhere else (I never worked much with managing DBs). I know the my solution is not ideal, but i'm trying to make the best with what i am given.

I have thought about:
- PowerAutomate being somehow an intermediary!?
- Users submitting going to an extra individual file that would then be synced to avoid overwriting

Comment: Regarding the info, i'll try to be more clear on what i am doing: I have a 2 step process. User provides Data of costs, cost center reference, what type of distribution to use. Second Step (immediatly after) they get the ID that was generated from the first submition and provide a breakdown detail or might even need to input values themselves and then the data from these 50+ users is all calculated based on SAP data that has been previously downloaded and updated to other sheets. Due to problems in the past we are using userforms now to limit the amount of user error.